# Why my methods interfering with each others and with if statements in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch

I have a form to insert some data in sql database with some conditions , First I need to check for nulls and alert the user :

```
void CheckNulls() {

    try {
        if (txtcode.Text.Length == 0 || txtItem.Text.Length == 0 || txtWh.Text.Length == 0) {

            MessageBox.Show("Fill Required Fields", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }

        else {
            checkExistAndDo();

        }

    }

    catch(Exception Err) {
        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

Then I need to check if the user checked any `checkbox` :

```
void checkExistAndDo() {

    if (chkProduct.Checked || chkMaterial.Checked)

    {

        if (chkProduct.Checked == true) {
            if (!chkMaterial.Checked) {
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [ProductCode] FROM Products Where [ProductCode] = @prcode ", Cn);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", txtcode.Text);
                dt.Clear();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {

                    MessageBox.Show("Existing Code", "Error");

                }
                else {

                    TakeAction();
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code FROM Items Where Code = @prcode ", Cn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", txtcode.Text);
            dt.Clear();

            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                MessageBox.Show("Existing Code", "Error");

            }
            else {

                TakeAction();
            }

        }

    }

    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Check even one", "check", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    }

}
```

So , I have 4 different combinations in total :

```
chkProduct.Checked : chkMaterial.Checked : Action
--------------------------------------------------------------
              true :                true : InsertSubProduct()
              true :               false : InsertProduct()
             false :                true : InsertMaterial()
             false :               false : Ask User to Check
```

Then I need to take action based on the combination :

```
private void TakeAction()
{
    try
    {

        if (chkProduct.Checked == true && chkMaterial.Checked == false)
        {


            InsertProduct();
            MessageBox.Show("Product Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        else if (chkProduct.Checked == false && chkMaterial.Checked == true)
        {

            InsertMaterial();
            MessageBox.Show("Material Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        else
        {
            InsertSubProduct();
            MessageBox.Show("SubProduct Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }

    catch (Exception Err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }

    finally
    {
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

The problem is that this part doesn't do anything not showing my message , Not even an error message as if it doesn't exist in my code :

```
       else
        {
            InsertSubProduct();
            MessageBox.Show("SubProduct Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Sorry for long post but i tried my best and debugged the code many times and i can't get pass this , Thanks in advance and your help is deeply appreciated .

Comment: Do separation of concerns better. `CheckNulls()` should only return a `bool`, and not show any messages to the user or call any other methods. `checkExistAndDo()` should not exist at all (that logic should be entirely in the database as part of `InsertProduct/MaterialSubproduct()`).

Comment: if `chkProduct.Checked` is true, checkExistAndDo will enter the first and second `if`, but not the third. And there is no `else` in this case.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for your reply , About cancelling `CheckExistAndDo` do you mean I should check if the code exist before every insert in my ` InsertProduct/Material/Subproduct())` methods ?

Comment: @CsharpNewbie Yes, you should do that, and do it in one single call into the database. Otherwise you'll have a race condition.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks for your reply , You are right in this phase there are only two conditions the first if the `ChkProduct` is checked it will search in table products , else it will search in table items then the `Take Action` will have to deal with the rest , Checks for the already checked CheckBoxes and activate the suitable action.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ok I will try that and comment back with the result , I appreciate your guiding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Joel Coehoorn comments I tried different approach
I quote " Do separation of concerns better. CheckNulls() should only return a bool, and not show any messages to the user or call any other methods. checkExistAndDo() should not exist at all (that logic should be entirely in the database as part of InsertProduct/MaterialSubproduct()). "

It worked great , Thanks all for replying , I appreciate your guiding .

Answer (score 0):

If the `ThreeState` property is set to true, the Checked property will return `true` for either a `Checked` or `Indeterminate` CheckState.

Check the `ThreeState` property for `chkMaterial` checkbox

Comment: Thanks for replying , ThreeState is set to false and the default state of the check boxes is unchecked.

Comment: You never called `TakeAction()` if both check boxes are checked in the `checkExistAndDo()` method!